# XML in C# to varbinary column in SQL

Tags: c#, encoding, xml-serialization, varbinary

I have an XmlDocument object that I load from a file.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("C:\\myxml.txt");
```

I need to convert this XML Document to a format that is compatible with varbinary in a SQL table.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skip the overhead of loading an XML document and then encoding by just reading the file as bytes directly:

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllbytes("C:\\myxml.txt");
```

The above uses System.IO

Then instert into SQL like so:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO myTable(myCol) VALUES(@file)", myDbConn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@file", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = data;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlDoc.OuterXml);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could save the XML into a memory stream, then save the resulting byte array in your `varbinary` column:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
xmlDoc.Save(ms);
ms.Position = 0;
byte[] xmlData = ms.ToArray();
```

*Ideally* you should switch to a XML type column though if possible (i.e. SQL Server) or just `nvarchar`.